# NightwatchJS not passing variable

Tags: javascript, scope, nightwatch.js

I've separated the variables for scoping purposes, I'm able to fill out all the variables with the respective DOM elements from url1 but when I try to pass them to url2 fields, they get set to `undefined` as if the variable was never set. Yet the console.log works... I've passed also a function to `.setValue('#address-serviceability-form', '', '', function(e){ // set the value here})` but still I get undefined... Is this variable scoping issue?

```
describe('Ecosia.org Demo', function() {
  var address ='';
  var streetNumber = '';
  var city = '';
  var stateAndZip = '';
  var state = ''
  var zip = '';

before(browser => browser.url('url1.com'));

test('Extract random address', function (browser) {

browser
  .getText('.rand_large li:first-child', function(result) {
    address = result.value.split("\n");
    streetNumber = address[0];
    console.log('streetNumber', streetNumber) //this works and logs correctly
    city = address[1].split(",")[0];
    stateAndZip = address[1].split(",")[1];
    state = stateAndZip.split(" ")[1];
    zip = stateAndZip.split(" ")[2];

  })
  .url('url2.com')
  .waitForElementVisible('form')
  .setValue('#address-serviceability-form', streetNumber) // this is set to undefined
  .pause(5000)
 });

 after(browser => browser.end());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me to be a problem with your understanding of NodeJS callbacks.

You should be able to fix this using async/await. Your code is not waiting for the callback to be resolved and the value is not assigned before being used in set value function. you could try something like below.

```js
test('Extract random address', async function(browser) {

  await browser
    .getText('.rand_large li:first-child', function(result) {
      address = result.value.split("\n");
      streetNumber = address[0];
      console.log('streetNumber', streetNumber) //this works and logs correctly
      city = address[1].split(",")[0];
      stateAndZip = address[1].split(",")[1];
      state = stateAndZip.split(" ")[1];
      zip = stateAndZip.split(" ")[2];

    })
  browser.url('url2.com')
    .waitForElementVisible('form')
    .setValue('#address-serviceability-form', streetNumber) // this is set to undefined
    .pause(5000)
});
```